# Photoshop: Keyboard shortcut to switch between Layer and Layer Mask

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, adobe-photoshop

What's the keyboard shortcut to toggle between a layer and it's mask in Photoshop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides shift click on the layer mask thumbnail, you can go to top Edit/keyboard Shortcuts menu. There, at "shortcuts for" field, choose "Applications menu". Deploy "Layer". Scroll till "Layer Mask". Scroll till "Enable - disable mask" (if said so). Choose the key (or keys) shortcut you prefer. And that's it.

Hoping is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> to switch from color to mask.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> to switch from mask to color.

This is probably what you were looking for, it switches between the selection of either the layer's color or mask instead of clicking on them in the layer list.

Comment: On OS X, the shortcuts are Command + \ and Command + 2

Answer (score 2):

To scroll through the layers in the Layers palette, hold down your <kbd>Alt</kbd> (Win) / <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> (Mac) key and use the left and right bracket keys ( <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> ). The right bracket key scrolls upward through the layers, and the left bracket key scrolls down.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>

and

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\ (Backslash)</kbd>

This is that you want

Answer (score 0):

Command-Shift backslash and Command-Shift 2 will actually switch between them so you can paint on them.